# JavaScript / Jquery me tira error en ajax al querer traer info de base de datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tengo mi código que llama a una función en `.net` que me trae unos datos de mi base de datos, mi función en `.net` funciona perfecto porque lo corroboro por `postman!`

Mi problema esta en **frontend**, cuando yo quiero llamar a esa funciona mediante un `ajax`, que le paso los parámetros que necesita, esperando que me devuelva algo.
No se cual es mi error, porque me parece que invoco bien a la función.
Simplemente quiero mostrar los resultados en consola, para saber por lo menos si me esta llegando a lo que quiero, pero no da resultado..

Les paso mi código

```js
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#mostrar_articulos", function() {
    // una vez dentro de #mostrar_articulos
  //Quiero que al apretar el boton! me tome los datos que tengo en mis h3, y que me ejecute el metodo 
  // ObtengoDato(); que hace la llamada a la base de datos
    $("#btnEjecutar").click(function() {
        var valorHSeccion = $("#hSecc").text();
        var valorHCategoria = $("#hCat").text();
        var valorHEstilo = $("#hEst").text();
        var valorHMarca = $("#hMarc").text();
        var valorHTall = $("#hTall").text();
        ObtengoDato(valorHSeccion, valorHCategoria, valorHEstilo, valorHMarca, valorHTall);
    });

});



function ObtengoDato(NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumeroTalle) {
    var dir = "ObtengoCandCla";
    //trim para quitar los espacios que vienen con los parametros
    NombreSeccion = $.trim(NombreSeccion);
    NombreCategoria = $.trim(NombreCategoria);
    NombreEstilo = $.trim(NombreEstilo);
    NombreMarca = $.trim(NombreMarca);
    NumeroTalle = $.trim(NumeroTalle);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion + "&NombreCategoria=" + NombreCategoria + "&NombreEstilo=" + NombreEstilo + "&NombreMarca=" + NombreMarca + "&NumeroTalle=" + NumeroTalle,
        success: function(datos) {
            var data = datos;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log("Funciona");
                console.log("Fabricante: " + data[i].Fabricante + ", Articulo: " + data[i].articulo + ", Descripcion: " + data[i].Descripcion + ", Color: " + data[i].color);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });

}
```

```html
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="mostrar_articulos">
       <div id="div_Articulos">
                <div class="div_res">
                    <h3 id="hSecc"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="div_res">
                    <h3 id="hCat"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="div_res">
                    <h3 id="hEst"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="div_res">
                    <h3 id="hMarc"></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="div_res">
                    <h3 id="hTall"></h3>
                </div>
       </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="btnEjecutar" value="Ejecutar">
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sale algún error en la consola? Podrías poner el HTML completo para ver si los tag `link` tienen algún problema?

Comment: este es el error que te aparece --> `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` ??

Comment: Hola, los errores que me tira son los 3 errores de consola de ajax, solamente esos, y repetidos 2 veces(tampoco se porque me los repite)

Comment: jquery-2.1.1.js:8623 GET http://192.168.41.205/comventa/api/ComVenta/ObtengoCandCla?NombreSeccion=HOMBRE&NombreCategoria=BOTA&NombreEstilo=BOTA%20DE%20LLUVIA&NombreMarca=AMERICAN%20SPORT&NumeroTalle=44 404 (Not Found) ----  me tira este error, como si tuviera mal la url, pero no es asi

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu controlador? para ver

Comment: De acuerdo al error que comentas que te sale (Notfound) es por que no estas poniendo la url correcta hacia tu controlador. Igual te falta indicar el tipo de dato que esperas recibir no sé si esperes un json o un xml. Específica que otros errores te salen en consola por favor.

Comment: Gracias tenia un error en la url, estaba poniendo mal un nombre dentro de las comillas